# Vueify, Browserify and (disabling) Hot Reload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

I've used `elixir` & `browserify` before. However, I want to start using `Vueify` so I can have all my component's parts (`HTML`/`CSS`/`JS`) in 1 file.

It seems something has changed with `laravel-browserify`

The commonly (that I have found) answer is the following:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var vueify = require('laravel-elixir-browserify').init("vueify");

elixir(function(mix) {
    // resources/assets/js/main.js
    mix.vueify('main.js', {insertGlobals: true, transform: "vueify", output: "public/js"});
});
```

This throws the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir/ingredients/commands/Utilities'
//...//
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BLANKED\Code\Project\node_modules\laravel-elixir-browserify\index.js:5:17)
```

So, some more searching around, and I find
https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/203

```
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'vueify'
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

`JeffreyWay`'s method will now `gulp`, however it doesn't seem to include any of the `*.vue` files, and instead replaces them with a `vue-hot-reload-api` function to presumably retrieve it.

Which seems great, and something that - no doubt - I will find very useful.
But it's not working, and I cannot figure out how to disable it.
And a very basic `Vue` *App* is not working. 
Or what I am doing wrong.

Edit:
To make it clear, I would be happy to `gulp` `*.vue` files without the hot reload working.
Perhaps this is something that just works when using homestead, but I'm hoping to do some quick & dirty testing without having to run up `homestead`.

Final edit:

```
//gulpfile.js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
 name: 'vueify'
});

elixir(function(mix) {
 mix.browserify('main.js');
});


// main.js
var Vue = require('vue')
var App = require('./app.vue')

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        app: App
    }
})

// app.vue
<style>
  .red {
    color: #f00;
  }
</style>

<template>
  <h1 class="red">{{msg}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function () {
      return {
        msg: 'Hello world!'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/commit/58c43723f6eab8bc920fce48e498640d481e2aca) Vueify is now included within Laravel Elixr. I found that when including the Vueify transformer manually it is run twice causing the template to not properly be created, leaving just the hot-reload code.

To fix the issue I just removed the following lines from my `gulpfile.js`.

```
elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers.push({
    name: 'vueify'
});
```

You may also have to ensure your version of laravel-elixr is over version `3.4.0`.

Comment: I will test this later this week.  
From digging through the `node_modules` folder, I saw `vueify` was in there.  
I didn't think not to tell `elixir` to use it. So that makes sense.
As I said, I will test later this week, and mark solved :)